# Battery showing charging when not plugged in on 2011 Macbook air Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, battery, macbook-air

So I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my 2011 Macbook Air and it's saying it's charging when I'm running off battery and vise versa. I don't know if this is a driver issue or what.

EDIT: Sometimes it acts normal but as soon as I plug it in it starts acting up.

Comment: When you say it's showing "charging" can you give a screenshot of the screen you are looking at?